# Pdf of a linear transformation $f(x)=1-|x| ,-1<x<1$. Find pdf of $Y=X^2$.

Tags: functions, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with density function $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 1 - |x| &\text{if }-1<x<1,\\ 0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$ Find the density function of $Y = X^2$. 
The answer given is $$f(y)= y^{-1/2} - 1 \qquad \text{ if   } \,\, 0<y<1$$
I would appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: You will need to break this into two parts: $[-1,0] \cup [0, 1]$ and then use the cdf technique if you are familiar with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly,observe that you can write $f(x)$ as $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1+x, & \text{ if } -1<x<0 \\ 1-x, & \text{ if } 0\le x<1 \\ 0, & \text{ otherwise } \end{cases}$$ Secondly, you can calculate $F_Y(y)$ as $$F_Y(y):=P(Y\le y)=P(X^2 \le y)$$ In order to proceed you need know to consider different cases for $y \in \mathbb R$.

1. $y\le 0$. Of course in that case $$F_Y(y)=P(X^2\le y)=0$$
2. $0< y <1$. In that case you can take the square root and proceed as follows: $$\begin{align*}F_Y(y):&=P(Y\le y)=P(X^2 \le y)=P(-\sqrt{y}\le X \le \sqrt{y})=\\&=\int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{0}(1+x)dx+\int_{0}^{\sqrt{y}}(1-x)dx=\\&=\sqrt{y}-\frac{y}{2}+\sqrt{y}-\frac{y}{2}=2\sqrt{y}-y\end{align*}$$ By differentiating with respect to $y$ you obtain that $$f_y(y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}F_Y(y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(2\sqrt{y}-y)=\frac{2}{2\sqrt{y}}-1=y^{-\frac{1}{2}}-1$$
3. $1\le y$. Since $X\le 1$ with probability $1$ you are also sure that $X^2\le 1$, thus $$F_Y(y)=P(X^2 \le y)=1$$ Of course in cases 1. and 3. differentiation gives you that $f_y(y)=0$ and therefore combining all cases you obtain that $$f_Y(y)=\begin{cases} y^{-\frac{1}{2}}-1, & \text{ if } 0<y<1, \\ 0, & \text{ otherwise }\end{cases}$$

Comment: thank you very much. I actually got 2y^(1/2)−y, but I forgot to differentiate it. sorry for wasting your time, my fault. thanks again

Comment: Do not worry, I have nothing useful to do with my time, so it is no problem